# aws route53 health check fails search string if response is a 302

Tags: amazon-route53, http-status-code-302, health-monitoring

I'm trying to use aws route53 for a health check using the search string feature. The site that im trying to monitor always returns 302 codes, and the health check passes if no search string is used, but fails if it's used.

Is there a way to make the health check search for the string, not on the 302 body, but on the redirected page? Or other workarround for this problem?

Comment: Workaround for which problem?  A `302` response is fine in and of itself, according to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-determining-health-of-endpoints.html), but it wouldn't generally make sense for a health check to follow a redirect.  Why is there a redirect?  If the redirect is on the same server, can't you just check *that* page directly?

Comment: Your right, it doesn't makes sense to health check following a redirect. The site uses a framework that does a lot of redirect trickery to show the content in the appropriate language, given the ip country of the request. I've finally found a page that returns a 200 code with a constant content despite the location of the health checker server. Thanks!